Node RedisOM auto-pipelining / saving in bulk
If I understand correctly, lets say I have an array of objects to save to redis:
const processedStandings: Standings[] =  processStandings(league, data)
for (const processedStanding of processedStandings){
    await standingsRepository.save(processedStandings)
}

What would be the optimal approach to save a bunch of objects?
I see a node article about auto-pipelining:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis

What that mean I could do this using premises. So something like:
const promises: Promise[] = {
    return processedStandings.map(processedStanding => {
        await standingsRepository.save(processedStandings)
    })
}

const results: number[] = await Promise.all(promises);

But in this case i believe I just do requests in parallel. But no auto pipelining is done?

Redis OM for Node.js will do pipelining as well. It just takes advantage of what Node Redis is doing under the covers. You're code is close, but you don't need to await the call to .save(). Just return the Promise instead.
Like this:
const promises = processedStandings.map(processedStanding => {
  return standingsRepository.save(processedStandings);
})

const results = await Promise.all(promises);

You could even get this in a single line if you really wanted to:
const results = await Promise.all(processedStandings.map(processedStanding => standingsRepository.save(processedStandings)));

Although that might be a bit much. 
